# List comprehension guards

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I am trying to take out every other element(starting with the first element in the list) using list comprehension , but I have encountered a problem - here is what I am trying to do

```
evother :: [a]-> Int  ->[a]
evother lst q  = [x | x <- lst, even( q++ ) ]
```

What I am trying to do is to increment a variable, q, by 1 every time even is evaluated (this would help me to get the desired list) . Obviously this doesn't work because q++ isn't allowed - what are my alternatives?

eg if I call: evother ['a','b','c'] 1 , then   even (2) is True and the first element (a) gets picked out, the second element 'b' will not get picked out because even (3) is False and finally 'c' will get picked out this gives us the list ['a','b']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with list comprehension

```
evother xs = [x | (x,i) <- zip xs [1..], even i]

> evother [1..10]
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

you can skip the list comprehension add the index with zip and filter

```
evother = map snd . filter (even . fst) . zip [1..]

> evother [1..10]
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

It's not clear from the description which elements you want to filter, so you can generalize this little bit

```
evother f = map snd . filter (f . fst) . zip [1..]

> evother even [1..10]
[2,4,6,8,10]

> evother odd [1..10]
[1,3,5,7,9]
```

However, a much nicer solution will be using mutual recursion

```
first, second :: [a] -> [a]
first [] = []
first (x:xs) = x:second xs
second [] = []
second (x:xs) = first xs

> first [1..10]
[1,3,5,7,9]

> second [1..10]
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @karakfa probably has the right answer but here is one using list comprehensions (note that I flipped the zip).

```
evother :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
evother lst q = [ x | (x,y) <- zip lst [q..], even( y ) ]
```